# Why does Performance Degrade with multiple calls to TableServiceContext.SaveChanges

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I was writing a quick client this morning to simply insert a bunch of data into table storage when I noticed that after subsequent saves, the performance would degrade.

```
public class MyObject : TableServiceEntity
{
    public MyObject()
    {
        this.RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have a simply chunk of code to add some data....

```
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            for (int i = 0; i < target / 50; i++)
            {
                CloudTableClient client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
                client.CreateTableIfNotExist(entitySet);
                TableServiceContext context = client.GetDataServiceContext();

                timer.Reset();
                timer.Start();
                for (int x = 0; x < i * 50; x++)
                {
                    var obj = new MyObject();

                    context.AddObject(entitySet, obj);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                total += 100;
                timer.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("Added 100 entities in {0} seconds; total: {1}", timer.Elapsed.Seconds, total);
            }
```

And here is what I see when it is run (Console App)

```
Added 100 entities in 0 seconds; total: 100

Added 100 entities in 0 seconds; total: 200

Added 100 entities in 1 seconds; total: 300

Added 100 entities in 2 seconds; total: 400

Added 100 entities in 4 seconds; total: 500

Added 100 entities in 4 seconds; total: 600

Added 100 entities in 6 seconds; total: 700

Added 100 entities in 6 seconds; total: 800
```

**Why does performance degrade?**

- It does not change if I move the **context, client, and/or account** out of the loop
- Implementing **context.ResolveType** did not resolve the issue
- After profiling, the context.SaveChanges method is where the bottleneck is
- Re-running the application reproduces the same results; even when there are hundreds/thousands of other entities in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your test code has a bug in it, in this line.

```
for (int x = 0; x < i * 50; x++)
```

You're iterating up to `i * 50` times, so each time through the outer loop you'll add 50 more entities than the previous time. The first time through you add 0 entities, which is very fast indeed. Then 50, then 100, then 150, etc. This is masked because your logging code blindly adds 100 to the count each time, even if that's not the number you actually added. What you probably wanted was:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
```

Regarding the profiling results, most of this code works on in-memory data. `SaveChanges()` does a network call, which is why it dominates the time spent.

I realize this is test code. But if you were actually trying to add a lot of entities to a single PartitionKey it would be advisable to use batches.

Comment: Thanks!  Its amazing how easy it is to overlook that!